# widget not response when i use progress manager killed the progress

Tags: java, android, widget, kill, progress

I have an android application with a widget, but when I use progress manager kill the app,after that ,I found 
the widget can not be used. I have some buttons in the widget.After I kill the app,I click these buttons and got no action. What causes this problem?

Comment: What language is this? what widgets? ect.. I cant answer anything by the information you have given.